# Sustituir valores por numeros Python

Tags: python, dataframe, diccionarios

Tengo un dataframe con esta estructura:

```
    Item(s) Item 1  Item 2  Item 3  Item 4  Item 5  Item 6  Item 7  Item 8  Item 9  ... Item 23 Item 24 Item 25 Item 26 Item 27 Item 28 Item 29 Item 30 Item 31 Item 32
0   4   citrus fruit    semi-finished bread margarine   ready soups NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   3   tropical fruit  yogurt  coffee  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   1   whole milk  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   4   pip fruit   yogurt  cream cheese    meat spreads    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Por otro lado tengo una lista con los valores de cada producto:

```
{1: nan, 2: 'decalcifier', 3: 'male cosmetics', 4: 'cake bar', 5: 'pudding powder', 6: 'curd', 7: 'frozen potato products', 8: 'other vegetables', 9: 'soap', 10: 'rice', 11: 'frankfurter', 12: 'liquor (appetizer)', 13: 'frozen fish', 14: 'cleaner', 15: 'candy', 16: 'coffee', 17: 'butter', 18: 'beef', 19: 'specialty chocolate', 20: 'Instant food products', 21: 'waffles', 22: 'spread cheese', 23: 'bathroom cleaner', 24: 'domestic eggs', 25: 'curd cheese', 26: 'pastry', 27: 'honey', 28: 'whole milk',
```

Cómo podría sustituir en el dataframe cada variable por su valor?? Es decir, q en todas las NaN pusieran un 1, decalcifier un 2...

Comment: Buen día, el diccionario lo tienes ya fijo? O es posible invertirlo?

Comment: Me valdría tanto fijo o pudiendo modificarlo siempre y cuando se mantengan los mismos valores en las distintas columnas. Es decir, que NaN siempre fuese 0, por ejemplo.

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Una forma muy fácil de hacerlo es utilizando el método [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), pero la estructura del diccionario sería invirtiendo tus llaves y tus valores. Es decir, en lugar de `1: nan` debería ser `nan: 1`

Por cierto, para poder sustituir los valores `NaN` debes utilizar [`numpy.nan`](https://interactivechaos.com/es/python/function/numpynan)

Utilizando una versión reducida (Solo 9 columnas) de las filas que pusiste en tu pregunta (Cree un archivo llamado sample.csv)

```
    Item(s) Item 1  Item 2  Item 3  Item 4  Item 5  Item 6  Item 7  Item 8  Item 9
0   4   citrus fruit    semi-finished   bread margarine ready soups NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   3   tropical fruit  yogurt  coffee  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   1   whole milk  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   4   pip fruit   yogurt  cream cheese    meat spreads    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

E invirtiendo el diccionario (Por cierto en tu pregunta sólo pusiste hasta 28 así que los demás valores no supe que ponerles)

```
d = {np.nan:1, 'decalcifier': 2, 'male cosmetics': 3, 'cake bar': 4,
     'pudding powder': 5, 'curd': 6, 'frozen potato products': 7, 'other vegetables':8,
     'soap': 9, 'rice':10, 'frankfurter':11, 'liquor (appetizer)': 12,
     'frozen fish': 13, 'cleaner': 14, 'candy': 15, 'coffee': 16,
     'butter': 17, 'beef': 18, 'specialty chocolate': 19, 'Instant food products': 20,
     'waffles': 21, 'spread cheese': 22, 'bathroom cleaner': 23, 'domestic eggs': 24,
     'curd cheese': 25, 'pastry': 26, 'honey': 27, 'whole milk':28}
```

Lo único que hay que hacer para que reemplace todo lo que venga en el Diccionario por sus valores es:

```
df.replace(d)
```

Ejemplo complete:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {np.nan:1, 'decalcifier': 2, 'male cosmetics': 3, 'cake bar': 4,
     'pudding powder': 5, 'curd': 6, 'frozen potato products': 7, 'other vegetables':8,
     'soap': 9, 'rice':10, 'frankfurter':11, 'liquor (appetizer)': 12,
     'frozen fish': 13, 'cleaner': 14, 'candy': 15, 'coffee': 16,
     'butter': 17, 'beef': 18, 'specialty chocolate': 19, 'Instant food products': 20,
     'waffles': 21, 'spread cheese': 22, 'bathroom cleaner': 23, 'domestic eggs': 24,
     'curd cheese': 25, 'pastry': 26, 'honey': 27, 'whole milk':28}

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df = df.replace(d)
```

Al imprimir `df` devuelve:

```
    Item(s) Item 1  Item 2  Item 3  Item 4  Item 5  Item 6  Item 7  Item 8  Item 9
0   4   citrus fruit    semi-finished   bread margarine ready soups 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1   3   tropical fruit  yogurt  16  1   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
2   1   28  1   1   1   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
3   4   pip fruit   yogurt  cream cheese    meat spreads    1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Como mencioné, los valores que no se sustituyeron es porque no existen en el diccionario por lo que tendrás que agregar los elementos faltantes.

**Nota:** Si no quieres que aparezcan como `float` puedes cambiar el tipo de dato a entero.